# java - adding values to a vector inside a for

Tags: java, for-loop, vector

So i have a vector with n elements and i was trying to give a certain value to each different "space" inside the vector and them use those values for another operation , so this is what i have done

```
double valorCompras(){
        double[] vcompras = new double[compra];
        double saldo = dinheiro;
        if (compra > 0)
            for( int u = 0 ; u < vcompras.length ; u++ ){
                vcompras[u] = sc.nextDouble();
                saldo -= vcompras[u];

            }
        System.out.println("ficou com "+saldo+" de saldo na conta");
        return saldo;   

    }
```

but wenever i run the program that uses the method it doesnt let me give any value to any of the vetor's spaces.
what can i do?
also im new to programing so please dont judge this question too hard.

also this is the rest of the code in which i use this method

```
switch (op) {
        case '1' : 
            System.out.println("Tem "+test1.orcamento()+"euros de saldo disponivel");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Efetuo compras no valor de "+test1.compras()+" euros");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Insira o valor de cada compra  a efetuar "+test1.valorCompras());
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("5 - Sair");
                do{
                    op = sc.next().charAt(0);
                    if( op != '5')
                        System.out.println("operacao invalida");
                }
                    while ( op != '5');
                if( op == '5')
                    ; break;
```

Comment: what is the value of compra

Comment: @StinePike: I'm guessing `0`!

Comment: compra is a scanner inserted value defined on another method , and even if compras is , lets say , 4 , it still wont let me give values to the vector

Comment: just a hint: if you're using english variable names it is easier to ask help and later it will be more supportable by others. I'm hungarian and I also use english variable names everywhere. :)

Comment: thank you for the hint , just changed the variable names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you provide more details:

1. What is the value of compra? Are you sure it is > 0 ?
2. what is sc ? Does sc.nextDouble actually return a double ?

**EDIT1:**
Tried this code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    valorCompras(new Scanner(System.in));
}

static double valorCompras(Scanner sc){
    int compra = 4;
    double  dinheiro = 5000;
    double[] vcompras = new double[compra];
    double saldo = dinheiro;

    if (compra > 0)
        for( int u = 0 ; u < vcompras.length ; u++ ){
            vcompras[u] = sc.nextDouble();
            saldo -= vcompras[u];

        }
    System.out.println("ficou com "+saldo+" de saldo na conta");
    return saldo;   

}
```

---

**INPUT** 
55
65
75
85

**OUTPUT**
ficou com 4720.0 de saldo na conta

**EDIT2**
The problem is elsewhere In Go.java The compras() method 
[int compra = sc.nextInt();] 
should be 
[compra = sc.nextInt();]

```
int compras(){
                    System.out.println("insira o numero de compras que pretende efetuar");
                    do{
                    int compra = sc.nextInt();
                    if(compra == 0)
                            System.out.println("Nenhuma compra efetuada");
                    }
                    while(compra < 0);
                            return compra;
            }
```

Comment: sc is my scanner name , the user imputs a double , so compra's value is determined by the user , but when i test it with compras = 4 , it still doesnt let me give values tot he vector

Comment: Works fine for me. See the code I ran and let me know if I am missing anything.

Comment: hum i dont think you missed anything , but i also think i might know whats wrong with my code but i have no clue how to fix it : so i have this class only with methods and another class with my main. i first call another method in which the user imputs the value of compra and then i call this method that requires variables defined in the previouse method. maybe if i joined the 2 methods in one it would fix it?

Comment: Maybe you could post the classes (removing any pvt information) so we can take a look. Just looking at the snippet, there seems no error.

Comment: i posted on this link the class with the methods pastebin.com/pgM5zdAc and in this one my main pastebin.com/qWhgf5aA

Comment: The compras() method is in Go.java. The problematic line is int compra = sc.nextInt(); Its your code, I figured you would identify that easily :)

Comment: sorry im new to thsi so i went and checked the pastebin link thats why i couldnt find any edit.
also yeah it did work , i had allready deffined the variale compras at the begining thats why it wasnt woking , thank you so much for the help :)

Comment: sorry for this kind of question but , how do you end the question?

Comment: Just accepting the answer is enough, which you have already done

Answer (score 0):

When I use your code in a little test setup like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    private static final Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        valorCompras(4, 4000);
    }

    private static double valorCompras(int compra, int dinheiro){
        double[] vcompras = new double[compra];
        double   saldo    = dinheiro;

        if (compra > 0) {
            for(int u = 0; u < vcompras.length; u++ ) {
                vcompras[u]  = sc.nextDouble();
                saldo       -= vcompras[u];
            }
        }

        System.out.println("ficou com " + saldo + " de saldo na conta");

        return saldo;
    }
}
```

And then give it following input:

```
100
100
100
200
```

It prints this output

```
ficou com 3500.0 de saldo na conta
```

What is absolutely expected!


So where exactly is your problem? May we see some more code?

Comment: hum well that is the expected output , the one mine is not giving , i will put now the rest of the code in which i use this method then.

Comment: What exactly does _it doesnt let me give any value to any of the vetor's spaces_ mean? When you input values, nothin happens or are you even not able to make an input?

Comment: im not able to imput values , after i give the value to compra it imidiatly jumps to the System.out.print(ficou com....) and then for some reason it also repeats that system.out.print(insira o valor...)  i clueless to why it does that

Comment: Maybe you can show us more code, actually the whole programm. [Pastebin](http://www.pastebin.com) might be the right place to upload when it's a longer code.

Comment: thank you for the advice , i posted on this lik the class with the methods http://pastebin.com/pgM5zdAc
and in this one my main http://pastebin.com/qWhgf5aA

Comment: You gave me a hard time with all that portuguese names and stuff but I think this might help you: http://pastebin.com/pfPz69Ww